# How to replace part of a URL request before proxying in apache 2.4?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I am trying to re-write part of a URL (`https://myfirstdomain.com/lool/https:/alf.mydomain.com/service/wopi/files/uuid?query_params`) before the proxying takes place and I have this relevant section in my default SSL vhost:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine   On
    LogLevel debug rewrite:trace3

    RewriteRule ^lool/https:/alf.mydomain.com\/(.*) lool/https://alf.mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,NE]
</IfModule>

ProxyPass               /       https://localhost:2323/
ProxyPassReverse        /       https://localhost:2323/
```

and I see this in the re-write logs:

```
applying pattern '^lool/https:/alf.mydomain.com' to uri '/lool/https:/alf.mydomain.com/service/wopi/files/uuid
```

but on the service that receives this I see that the URL hasn't been re-written. Would be grateful for any clues as to what I am doing wrong. I am essentially trying to add the extra `/` that has been removed by a proxy server somewhere in the infrastructure that I do not have access to.

**EDIT:**
in the logs for the backend WOPI service, it sees the request URL un-modified:

```
Request from 127.0.0.1:42035: GET /lool/https:/alf.mydomain.com/service/wopi/files/uuid
```

Comment: In what context is this directive being used? Server config / virtual host? Or _directory_ context? The format of your directive assumes the later. However, that directive only matches the first part of the example URL you posted?

Comment: @MrWhite virtual host for the default SSL virtual host. The pattern is meant to match the [lool/https:/alf.mydomain.com] and insert the missing / so I'm not sure I understnd what you're getting at. Is something wrong with the pattern?

Comment: Your example URL contains `/service/wopi/files/uuid` - but you make no reference to this (or any wildcard pattern matching) in your directive? Just checking... how is the "service that receives this" parsing the URL? It's just that if they match this using a `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (like you are doing), then they will only ever see a single slash. mod_rewrite reduces multiple slashes in the URL-path that is matched by the `RewriteRule` _pattern_.

Comment: @MrWhite currently the service receiving the URL receives the request unmodified.

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks for the clue in matching the rest of the URL, I have update the question to reflect the changes made. I however still see no change in the error in the proxied service's logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^lool/https:/alf.mydomain.com\/(.*) lool/https://alf.mydomain.com/$1 [QSA,NE]
> ```

When used in a *virtual host* context, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the full URL-path, including the slash prefix (this is only removed in a *directory* context).

Try something like the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^/lool/https:/(alf\.mydomain\.com/.*) /lool/https://$1 [PT,NE]
```

The slash prefix is also required on the *substitution* when used in a virtual host context, in order to specify a document-root relative URL-path.

I've just extended the captured pattern to include the hostname to save repetition in the *substitution*.

Literal dots should be escaped in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. Whereas slashes (`/`) do not need to be escaped.

The `QSA` flag is superfluous here since you aren't specifying a query string on the *substitution*.

You may or may not need the `PT` (`passthrough`) flag in order to get this picked up by mod_proxy.

You should also remove the `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper - unless this is intended to work without mod_rewrite? Otherwise, you'll just mask an errors when mod_rewrite is not available.

Comment: Is it possible to encode everything after the "/lool/" ? I tried substituting the :\\ characters with their utf-8 encode but that didn't work

Comment: Remove the `NE` (`noescape`) flag from the `RewriteRule` directive. The default action is to URL encode the _substitution_. The `NE` flag specifically instructs the rewrite engine not to URL encode the resulting _substitution_. (Presumably you mean `://`, not `:\\ `?) However, `://` will still not be URL encoded - this is something you would need to do when making the request. (TBH It would be easier to use the query string, rather than the URL-path for something like this.)